# Tails USB won't boot in ubuntu MATE 15.04

Tags: boot, usb, 15.04, mate

I have Ubuntu MATE 15.04 as my primary OS. I made a tails bootable usb but when I try to log in with it i get:

No Caching mode page found

Assuming drive cache:  write through

then it continues to log normally my OS.

My legacy bios is enabled and my boot order is correct.
USB is a FAT32 format and the installation of tail was done without errors.

I have searched for 3 days now but I can't find something that works so I decided to post here.

My laptop is a Dell inspiron 5558, i5, 8g ram , 2t hdd.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try using rufus tool to make your bootable media [of course on a windows machine]. I faced a quite similar issue but rufus did it for me. It automatically decides which boot mode is perfect for your iso image.....if rufus asks for syslinux files, use [these](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/cbfc1c63) extract the folder to ./rufus_files/syslinux-6.03 and you are good to go.

Comment: I made my tails usb, through cloning tails from virtualbox. I will try your method. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, so by making a bootable usb with rufus I was indeed able to use tails!   It doesn't let me make a persistent volume though because I didn't use Tails installer, I don't know if you also run into the same problem.

Comment: what i have found is that vmware is a better virtual machine than virtual box. virtual box has had issues with linux images......tried installing  android on virtual box, ran into a reboot loop, tried vmware,,,worked perfect..so my suggestion is try migrating from virtualbox to vmware